# How to identify a dynamic id for drag n drop in cypress

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

[image: pls click here to see detail]

I am using this plagin https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop

Here id is generating dynamically - so using id its not being possible to identify. What could be alternate ways?
cy.get('itemlocation').drag('target location')
Here I cant identify the target location as id is dynamic :(
Its actually one stack panel and it has 3 columns with dynamic ids. Full pic is [click for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZCeT.png)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few possibilities,

- `.drag('.cdk-drop-list')` - if there's only one drop target
- `.drag('.cdk-drop-list:eq(2)')` - 3rd drop target
- `.drag('designer-stack-panel:nth-child(1)')` - only one stack panel, it's 1st child
- `.drag('designer-stack-panel:eq(1):nth-child(1)')` - 2nd stack panel, 1st child

Ref [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Its actually one stack panel and it has 3 columns with dynamic ids. See full pic added

Comment: So `:nth-child()` will have 1,2, or 3 depending on where you want to drop.

Comment: .drag('designer-stack-panel:nth-child(X)') here in place of x using 0,1,2, nothing works!

Comment: using .drag('designer-stack-panel:nth-child(X)') test cases running, no error shows but it cant drag the item. Just remain as it is.

Comment: cy.get('.field-label').drag('.cdk-drop-list.flex-grow.container.list.flex-column.ng-star-inserted:eq(0)')  can select the target stack but drag is not happening!  Any idea why? @Hiram K. Hackenbacker

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9355411/bkucera... Any idea from you..